# How do you configure a \\domain\sharedFolder in windows 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share

Background:

- I've got several Windows 2008 servers setup by someone else.
- They are all on one domain, lets call this `mydomain`
- Several boxes are accessing a shared folder by going to `\\mydomain\share1`
- I found the actual files backing the share on `box1`
- I need to move the location of this share to a larger drive for space reasons

I'm familiar with setting up and managing shares like `\\box1\share1`, but where do you manage/configure shares that are domain-wide; accessed like `\\mydomain\share1` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you have a domain based DFS configured, which is managed by the [DFS Management utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732006.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

DFS is Windows Distributed File System feature.  It allows you to apply a virtual path overtop of a physical path.  A great feature that allows the movement of shares between servers without the apparent path changing.  It also allows for multiple copies, and redundancy.

More about DFS can be found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757042(WS.10).aspx

As Bryan says the DFS Mgmt utility is where to go to make changes.  You may want to read a bit and test any changes before trying it live.

Answer (score 1):

As others stated, you have a domain based DFS namespace configured.

If you log into `box1` and go to Admin Tools in the Control Panel, there should be the DFS Management MMC console.  This is where you would manage the Domain Based DFS.

There are 2 main components to consider: the Namespace, and Replication.

The namespace (i.e. `share1`) in a domain based DFS config is hosted by one or more servers. You could have multiple namespaces (you could add `Share2`) and you can have subfolders (Folder Targets) within a namespace (i.e. \mydomain\share1\Marketing & \mydomain\share1\Sales).  The folder target creates a virtual path to an actual share path on a server.  So for \mydomain\share1\Marketing, the data may be actually at \box1\share\marketing.  You could add additional servers as folder targets.  so \mydomain\share1\Marketing could point to both \box1\share\marketing & \box2\share\marketing.

Your namespace is likely hosted on `box1`.  You can find out in the DFS console by expanding "Namespaces", clicking on "share1" and then switching to the "Namespace Servers" tab.

You can also configure data replication between servers for a Folder Target (\Marketing).
If you want more information on setting up the replication check out the [Step by Step Guide.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732863%28WS.10%29.aspx)

To move the location of the share you just need to add the new server with more capacity in as a folder target for `share1` in the DFS Console.

You could set the new target to replicate the data over from the first, then when the replication is up to date, remove the old server as a folder target.

If your namespace is hosted on `box1` you would want to add the new server in as a namespace server before removing `box1` as a folder target / namespace server.  Otherwise your clients will not be able to access the DFS paths.

Comment: Very Helpful - Thanks for the replication tips too.